# Render view from nancy bootstrapper?

Tags: c#, nancy

Is it possible to render a view outside of a NancyModule? For example, I want to be able to render a view in an error pipeline like so:

```
public class MyBootstrapper: DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{

    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        pipelines.OnError += ((ctx, e) =>
        {

            if (context.Request.Headers.Accept.Any(c => c.Item1.Equals("text/html")))
            {
                // Render view using e here
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by extracting the ViewFactory from the container:

```
public class MyBootstrapper: DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{

    protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        pipelines.OnError += ((ctx, e) =>
        {

            if (context.Request.Headers.Accept.Any(c => c.Item1.Equals("text/html")))
            {
                 IViewFactory viewFactory = container.Resolve<IViewFactory>();
                 return viewFactory.RenderView("Error", new {Message = ex.Message}, new ViewLocationContext() { Context = context, ModuleName = "", ModulePath = "" });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

No idea if the blank ModuleName & ModulePath will break anything, but it seems to work.